# pandas to_sql insert ignore

Tags: python, pandas

I want to incrementally keep adding data frame rows into MySQL DB avoiding any duplicate entries to go in MySQL.

I am currently doing this by looping through every row using df.apply()and calling MySQL insert ignore(duplicates) to add unique rows into MySQL database. But using pandas.apply is very slow(45 secs for 10k rows). I want to achieve this using pandas.to_sql() method which takes 0.5 secs to push 10k entries into DB but doesn't support ignore duplicate in append mode.
Is there an efficient and fast way to achieve this?

Input CSV

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
1994-01-03,111.7,112.75,111.55,112.65,0
1994-01-04,112.68,113.47,112.2,112.65,0
1994-01-05,112.6,113.63,112.3,113.0,0
1994-01-06,113.02,113.43,112.25,112.62,0
1994-01-07,112.55,112.8,111.5,111.88,0
1994-01-10,111.8,112.43,111.35,112.25,0
1994-01-11,112.18,112.88,112.05,112.4,0
1994-01-12,112.38,112.82,111.95,112.28,0
```

code

```
nifty_data.to_sql(name='eod_data', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False) # option-1 
nifty_data.apply(addToDb, axis=1) # option-2 

def addToDb(row):
    sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO eod_data (date, open, high, low, close, volume) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    val = (row['Date'], row['Open'], row['High'], row['Low'], row['Close'], row['Volume'])
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()`
```

`option-1: doesn't allow insert ignore (~0.5 secs)`

`option-2: has to loop through and is very slow (~45 secs)`

Comment: What happens if you use a lambda function? `nifty_data.apply(lambda x: addToDb(x))`  Really, though, you should be using pyodbc or SQLAlchemy when working with database transactions.  Pandas is slow at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a temporary table:

```
nifty_data.to_sql(name='temporary_table', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

And then run an INSERT IGNORE statement from that:

```
with engine.begin() as cnx:
    insert_sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO eod_data (SELECT * FROM temporary_table)'
    cnx.execute(insert_sql)
```

just make sure the column orders are the same or you might have to manually declare them.

Comment: This brings down the time to ~ 1 sec. Which is good. Thanks @OhMyGawd

Comment: @pedrogfp Can you please tell what is the postgreSQL equivalent of INSERT IGNORE? I saw that there is option called "ON CONFLICT (col) DO NOTHING" but i want to check for multiple columns..

Comment: note that with this you will lose pandas columns check. So if you change the structure of the eod_data table the data will end up in different columns